# $|(ix)!| = \frac{\pi x}{\sinh \pi x}$ using gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

I need to prove:

$$|(ix)!| = \frac{\pi x}{\sinh \pi x}$$

I already have this formula:

$$z!(-z)!= \frac{\pi z}{\sin \pi z}\tag{1}$$

I never used gamma for complex values. It is still valid that $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$, right? So I should try and see that $(ix)! = \frac{\Gamma(ix+1)}{ix+1}$ but I don't see how that helps. Also, the way that formula $1$ is derived in my book is by using Legendre's formula for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$, so I don't think my reasoning would work for what I wanted to prove.

Or I should just use formula $1$ and apply it for the value $z = 0+ix$ and take its absolute value...

$$|(0+ix)!(0-ix)!| = \left| \frac{\pi ix}{\sin \pi ix}\right|$$

but I don't quite get $|(ix)!|$ on the left...

Comment: The identity you're after isn't correct as written: it's $|(ix)!|^2$ rather than $|(ix)!|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that Euler's Reflection Formula is given by

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} \tag 1$$

Letting $z=-ix$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, in $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(-ix)\Gamma(1+ix)&=\frac{\pi}{\sin(-i\pi x)}\\\\
&=i\frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi x)}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Next, using the functional equation $\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma(z)$ in $(2)$, we obtain

$$\Gamma(1-ix)\Gamma(1+ix)=\frac{\pi x}{\sinh(\pi x)}$$

Finally, denoting $\Gamma(z+1)=z!$, we see that

$$|(ix)!|^2=\frac{\pi x}{\sinh(\pi x)}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Not entirely sure on this.  I get
$$|(ix)!(-ix)!|=\frac{\pi x}{\sinh(\pi x)}$$
What magic manipulations did you do?

Comment: @simplybeautifulart Then, we agree, do we not?

Comment: I do not think it is so immediate on $z!=\bar z!$.

Comment: Use the integral representation for $\text{Re}(z)>0$.  It follows immediately that $\overline{\Gamma(1+ix)}=\Gamma(1-ix)$.